# Personal Campaign Page - no WordPress User account being created

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, personal-campaign-pages

I am using the **Personal Campaign Page** functionality in CiviCRM, but I am finding that **no** **WordPress Account** is being created for the Contact creating their Personal Campaign Page.
The Profile selected in Personal Campaigns tab of the Payment/Contribution Page is configured with the setting '***Account creation required***'.

Is there anything else that must be configured in order for the Supporter to create their own User Account?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have 'Anyone can register' enabled with the WP general settings?

Comment: Many thanks for this! This was the reason why no WP User account was being created

Comment: Having that WP setting enabled, how the user can choose or know their own password? I think the system automatically generates a password, but there is no option to be set up by the users themselves or know what it is by them. Is it the only possible option to click on "Lost your password" when trying to log in?

Comment: WP will also (usually) send an email at the point the user is crated that states their username and "To set your password, visit the following address:"